# How to restore scripts history in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 html pages. in page A, some script is active. When the user performs some action, some of these scripts work. When Click on a button occurred, it will go to the second page.  I'm going to click on the back button in page B, to return to the first page occurs, while the recent changes that have occurred with the scripts be valid. But it's not, and when i come back to the first page, the page is loaded to its original state.

Comment: You generally can't, HTML is stateless, and so is javascript in the browser enviroment. You'd have to device some sort of system that stores the changes the user does and then write a script that reimplements those changes, there are no silver bullets.

Comment: @adeneo what is stateless? HTML or HTTP?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com - well, `http` is, I mistakenly wrote HTML, wich is just a languge